# Unicode and other codings compatibility

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, standards

128 first Unicode characters is compatible with ASCII.

Is 256 first Unicode characters compatible with any extended ASCII standards?

Is 512 first Unicode characters compatible with any other coding standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 128 code positions have been taken directly from ASCII. However, there are slightly different versions of the ASCII standard and, moreover, various 7-bit codes (now largely unused) have been called “national variants of ASCII”.

There is no “extended ASCII”. ASCII is a 7-bit code. Most character codes used in the world have positions 0 1o 127 taken from ASCII, so they might be called “extensions to ASCII”, but this would be rather pointless.

The next 128 characters in Unicode have been taken from ISO 8859-1.

(Regarding control characters, in C0 Controls and C1 Controls, the standards formulate things somewhat differently. In any case, the meanings of most of those control characters are defined in other standards and specifications, as they are not really a matter of character code standardization.)

There is nothing special about the next 256 characters in terms of relationship with other standards. Their allocation was not based on any previous standard.

Comment: Did you mean order of next 256 charters are chosen randomly?

Comment: @Reza, no, it was not random, but it was a novel allocation. The next 256 characters do not even constitute a single block but the Latin Extended-A block (U+0100 to U+017F) and the start of the next block, Latin Extended-B. Within these blocks, the order is mostly alphabetic. Extended-A was added mostly to cover those Latin letters used in European languages that are not in Basic Latin (ASCII) or in Latin-1 Supplement (for Western European languages). Various old 8-bit codes contain various subsets of these characters, scattered around the coding space.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the first 256 Unicode characters correspond to ISO 8859-1.

The first 512 characters would make a 9-bit encoding, which probably does not exist.

Comment: That's not really true. If you encode them as UTF-8, it's true.

Comment: It is really true. I'm talking about the represented characters, not how they're encoded.